# python code runs well; when installed using `pip`, it runs twice

Tags: python-3.x, pip, execution

I've written my self a program in python, that you can find [here](https://github.com/laimaretto/logChecker). It's a code to compare logs. When I run it as a python script, it runs well. See an example:

```
$ python3 src/logChecker/logChecker.py -pre logs_pre/ -post logs_pos/ -tf templ/
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pre/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pos/ #####
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json

Saving Excel
# 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template
# 1 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template
# 2 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template
# 3 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template
```

However, if I do install it using `pip` such as `pip3 install logChecker`, when invoked, the program runs twice.

```
$ pip3 show logChecker
Name: logChecker
Version: 3.5.6
Summary: A simple log analysis tool
Home-page: https://github.com/laimaretto/logChecker
Author: Lucas Aimaretto
Author-email: laimaretto@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: /home/lucas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pandas, textfsm, ttp, XlsxWriter
Required-by:


$ logChecker -pre logs_pre/ -post logs_pos/ -tf templ/
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pre/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pos/ #####
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json

Saving Excel
# 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template
# 1 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template
# 2 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template
# 3 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Successfully Loaded Templates from folder templ/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pre/ #####
##### Logs Loaded Successfully from folder logs_pos/ #####
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
0 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
1 0 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
2 0 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template agg01.cpe_rx.json
3 0 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template agg01.cpe_rx.json

Saving Excel
# 0 sh_rtr_opsf_op_db.template
# 1 sh_rtr_bgp_neigh.template
# 2 sh_rtr_rt_tbl_summ.template
# 3 sh_rtr_ospf_neigh.template
```

I'm clueless. If the program would run twice when invoked from within python, then I would have a starting point. But it's only running twice after being installed by `pip` and used as a normal program from the CLI.

I've already checked the `setup.py` (which is available in the [git repo](https://github.com/laimaretto/logChecker)), but it looks rather standard.

Unfortunately I don't have a minimal code to share; only the original code in [here](https://github.com/laimaretto/logChecker). But if someone has faced something similar, may be a hint or experience will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. It's two-fold.

First part is in the code itself. When I run it as a python script, this is what I see in the code that allows me to run it.

```
def main():
     [...my code..]

main()
```

That's why it runs when invoked from within Python.

However, when installing it using `pip`, I have the following inside `setup.py`.

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['logChecker=src.logChecker.logChecker:main'],
    },
```

The path for `console_scripts` points to the `main` function, which in the code itself it exists twice: a) as a definition and b) as a call to it.

I've removed the call to `main()` and now it runs once when invoked from the CLI. The downside of this is that I no longer can run it as a python script. I'll find a solution for that.

Comment: "*I've removed the callable main()*" Another approach is `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`. PS. BTW you didn't remove the callable, you removed the call to it; the callable is `def main` and the call is `main()`.